# NSUndoManager with TouchesEnded for MKPolyline

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay, nsundomanager, mkpolyline

This is my first time trying to use NSUndoManager and i'm not sure where I should be putting it/what i'm missing. I'm making an application that has a map view with a draw button and undo button. I have the draw button enable the user to draw a polyline and every time their finger leaves the screen it connects another line to the line they just drew. I want the undo button to get rid of the last line that they drew.

some of what I have so far...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
...
...
undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc]init];
}

- (IBAction)oopsButton:(id)sender {

[undoManager undo];

}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
....
....
[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]touchesEnded:(touches) withEvent:event];
[undoManager setActionName:NSLocalizedString(@"Route Changed", @"route undo")];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay

...
...
```

right now, when I click undo, it undoes one line but that's all. I need it to keep undoing for as many times as the user clicks. Thanks for any help on this, i've been looking all over google and stack and haven't found anything that helps yet.

Comment: But we actually need to see your implementation of `touchesEnded:`.

Comment: BTW, what I suggest you do is forget about MKPolyline, forget about maps, forget about touches. Just think about a button that, when tapped, adds one line or square or other object to an existing drawing, and another button for undoing that. Think about how you make that series of drawn objects undoable one by one - and redoable one by one! Implement that. This should cause things to click into place. Once you've see through that one, you'll be ready to adapt it to your actual case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to update the polyline without using undo manager...

```
- (IBAction)oopsButton:(id)sender {

    //remove last point from array
[self.coordinates removeLastObject];

    //update line on map
NSInteger numberOfPoints = [self.coordinates count];

if (numberOfPoints > 1)
{
    MKPolyline *oldPolyLine = self.polyLine;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D points[numberOfPoints];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        points[i] = [self.coordinates[i] MKCoordinateValue];
    MKPolyline *newPolyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:points count:numberOfPoints];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:newPolyLine];

    self.polyLine = newPolyLine;

    if (oldPolyLine)
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:oldPolyLine];

}
}
```